# Hide UIViewController when presenting modal viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a main `UIViewController`.

When the user is not logged in, in the body of the main viewcontroller `viewDidAppear` I present a Login **modal** without any animation.

Problem is, when tested on a real device, for an instant I can see the presenting viewController.

I apparently solved by adding, in the main viewcontroller `viewDidLoad`,

```
self.view.isHidden = true;
```

but I wanted to know if there are better solutions (in this case, for example, I must remember to assign a `false` to the presenting `UIViewController.view.isHidden` when the user successfully logs in and the modal is dismissed).

Any advice is appreciated   :-)

Comment: Why don't you start the app with an `UIViewController` which looks like your startup screen and then show either the login controller or the controller for logged in users?

Comment: The main reason is the Login screen can be presented by many other uiviewcontrollers

Comment: @3000 You can implement another storyboard to Login screen. It's easy to manage!

Comment: @Mannopson: another storyboard? And how would this solve the problem of the same viewcontroller presented by many different viewcontrollers? You must not imagine the login screen at the entry point of the app   :-)

Comment: @3000 No I meant you can present a view controller by loading from another storyboard. It's very useful for login screens. It's just recommendation and not anything else.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway  :-)

Comment: Load LoginVC as root and do not show mainVC if user is not logged in.

Comment: @kirander: LoginVS is loaded from different uiviewcontrollers (different states of the app), it's not the entry point of the app

Comment: It does not matter. Before showing mainVC from some entry point check if a user is not logged in and show LoginVC instead.

Comment: @kirander: and when the user dismisses the modal? Should I "redirect" (!) him to some deeply nested viewcontroller?

Comment: Another solution is to add LoginVC as a child vc covering whole parent vc in some load time (init, viewDidLoad, etc)

Comment: That's the current solution!  :-)

Comment: no, instead to present it as modal, you just add LoginVC view as subview and make mainVC be parent of LoginVC.

Comment: This is quite interesting, I'll think into it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

In MainVC viewDidLoad:

```
if (user.isNotLoggedIn) {
  LoginVC *loginVC = [LoginVC new];
  [self addChildViewController:loginVC];
  loginVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
  [self.view addSubview:loginVC.view];
  [loginVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

In LoginVC after logged in:

```
    [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
```

But it is better to remove LoginVC from MainVC via delegating and add some view animation like fading or sliding.